# What is the function of enumerate in my code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, enumerate

i've done a bit of code that basically finds the index of words in a sentence but i don't really understand what i've done and the what is the function of the enumerate ?

```
    sentence = ['The', 'cat','sat', 'on', 'the', 'mat']
    for index, word in enumerate(sentence):
        print (index, word)
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate

Comment: The pupose of Stack Overflow isn't tutorial. It is exceedingly easy to find information online about what `enumerate` does in Python.

Answer (score 1):

the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#enumerate) will tell you more then you need to know:

> Return an enumerate object. iterable must be a sequence, an iterator, or some other object which supports iteration. The `__next__()` method of the iterator returned by enumerate() returns a tuple containing a count (from start which defaults to 0) and the values obtained from iterating over iterable.
>
> Equivalent to:

```
def enumerate(sequence, start=0):
    n = start
    for elem in sequence:
        yield n, elem
        n += 1
```